# Analyzing a function with abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

For an $n$-tuple $S$ of decreasing positive integers, we can define $f(S)$ as subtracting $1$ from every element of $S$, prepending $n$, and then removing $0$s and re-ordering in decreasing order if neccecary. For example, $f((4,2,1))=(3,3,1)$

We are just learning group theory, and our teacher asked us if we can use it to prove that all tuples will eventually reach a cycle when repeatedly applying this function.

My idea is using $f$ as our sort of group action acting on the set of finite decreasing tuples of positive integers, and then the proof would just be proving all elements have finite order, but I've hit a speedbump - a group action has to be a composition of two elements, i.e $x\cdot y$. This is a function that's just applied to one. I thought of maybe symmetric groups because I heard those have composition as a group action but their elements are functions so I don't think that's helpful here.

So how can this function be analyzed from a group-theoretic perspective?

EDIT: Accidentally deleted this, I just un-did it. Hope I didn't mess up anything.

Comment: Note that this is a re-write of an earlier question of mine that was put on hold as unclear. I hope I've clarified the confusions.

Comment: Group actions on a set aren't compositions, they are functions. Specifically, given a set $X$ and a group $G$, then a $G$-action on $X$ is a collection of functions $f_g:X\to X$, one for each element $g\in G$, satisfying certain niceness conditions. One could hope that $\langle f\rangle$ in this case could be a group, but unfortunately it isn't, since $f$ doesn't have an inverse (we have $f(1, 2) = f(2, 1)$, for instance).

Comment: @Arthur We’re only working here with decreasing sets of positive integers, though - if we use those as our set instead of all tuples does it change anything?

Comment: We still get things like $f(5, 2, 1) = f(4, 2, 1, 1)$

Comment: @Arthur So you are of the opinion that we can't use group theory to prove the statement above? Even indirectly?

Comment: I don't know. Just that the immediate approach is not going to work. There may still be ways to do it.

Comment: @MorganRodgers The question was just to prove whether all tuples will eventually reach a cycle when repeatedly applying this function. I thought it might be related to group theory because he used some group-theoretic terms, evidently that was wrong. Should I post a new question asking it more generally?

Comment: You can relate this naturally to [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) and monoid actions. If $f$ was invertible, you'd be able to make a group action out of it, but $f$ isn't invertible.

Comment: @DerekElkins Great thinking! Seriously thank you. We have talked about those before. Any insight on how you could use it's properties as a monoid to prove all tuples reach a cycle upon repeated iteration?

Comment: @DerekElkins Although that is still confusing - monoid actions are functions from $S \times S \rightarrow S$, how could this function be considered an action?

Comment: Actually, my previous comment was based on the previous version of the question and the previous definition of $f$. The new definition, restricted to sorted lists, may be invertible.

Comment: @NMister Monoid actions are, for a monoid $M$, functions $M\times X\to X$  satisfying some laws.

Comment: @DerekElkins Do you see any path, though, through groups or monoids, to lead to the statement that you will always end in a cycle?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to prove that if $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is your tuple then you only have a finite number of elements in the sequence $$x,f(x),f(f(x)),\dots $$

> Hint: look at the sum of the elements constituting the tuple in $x$ and in $f(x)$.

If you do this then you will necessarily reach twice the same element in the sequence and thus it will lead to a cycle.

Remark: I wouldn't say it is about group theory (maybe about the monoidal action of $\{Id,f,f^2,f^3,\dots\}$). However, I can see why this kind of reasoning is used to show basic group theoretic statements such as: in a finite group $G$, for any $g\in G$, there exists $n_g\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g^{n_g}=g^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I've proved that you only have a finite number of elements, but from there how can I prove that all tuples that sum to the same thing will approach the same cycle?